# Is this expression displayed by protestors antisemitic?

Tags: protests, rhetoric, antisemitism

Reading the news after four people were stabbed in protester-counterprotester clashes in Washington, DC — this image from [npr.org](https://www.npr.org/2020/12/12/945825924/trump-supporters-arrive-in-washington-once-again-for-a-million-maga-march) — I came across this potentially offensive picture:

> [image: counterprotesters]

(Hover over to view)

It's pretty clear that these are very far-left protesters. "Black Lives Matter," and the more radical  "Ch**** la Migra," "Defund the Police," and "We keep us safe" signs make that pretty obvious.

However, what I'm confused about is the center sign — "Jews will replace you."  I'm not familiar with that phrase, but it sounds (at least to me, a non-Jewish person) very, very antisemitic. It seems more in tune with the Proud Boys and other groups on the opposing side, bringing to mind all those crazy conspiracy theories of Zionism and George Soros and Jews controlling the world. I… *guess* it can be interpreted as radically *anti*-antisemitic, but it really doesn't sound like that.

Although the person holding the shield is clearly a counterprotester, and antisemitism is not really what they're famous for. Is this is the latter interpretation then?

But what I'm asking here is what that expression *usually* means. Is this exact phrase used often, or was it invented with that painted shield? If the former, **is it used more often in an antisemitic context or is it meant to strongly oppose antisemitism**? Why would an ostensibly far-left counterprotester show it when many of the far-right protesters they are countering (especially the Proud Boys, various other groups, and anyone seen with a "white power" gesture) believe in exactly that?

I realize I'm dealing with an especially delicate subject here. Please tell me if there is anything even remotely offensive with this post, or even if there are any awful grammar issues here, and correct them. Thank you in advance.

Comment: While anti-Semitism, racism, sexism, and so forth certainly influence politics, I do not think the question of whether serving is or is not anti-Semitic is a question about politics, government, or political processes. What context it is used in is on-topic, but the question does not really focus on that.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Okay. What would you suggest to improve this question? Or what site should I repost this on?

Comment: @Obie2.0 In this context, it is a political question. It's mocking a slogan advocating political action.

Comment: @Accumulation - The question of what it means to those who use it or whether it tends to be used by avowed anti-Semitic groups is a political question. The question of whether it "is" anti-Semitic is not, and is probably highly subjective to boot. Some might say "No, they mean it ironically and the purpose is to criticize anti-Semitic conspiracy theories," while others might say "Irony and positive intent don't necessarily eliminate the intrinsic character of a symbol", and still others might say "Its effect on (possibly only Jewish) observers is what matters, positive or negative".

Comment: So... in retrospect I probably should have expected that this post would cause trouble on this site. It's already been closed and reopened, and @Obie2.0 you're right, it doesn't fit in this site. Should I close it or delete it? Is there any reason *not* to take it down that I don't know about?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's a taunt, based on the chant "Jews will not replace us" [famous for being used by far right groups at Charlottesville](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2017/aug/16/charlottesville-neo-nazis-vice-news-hbo). The intent is almost certainly to incite a reaction, not to make an actual statement for or against the Jewish faith.

Comment: Indeed, sometimes stated as ["You Will Not Replace Us
"](https://www.adl.org/education/references/hate-symbols/you-will-not-replace-us)

Comment: As for the counter,  a bit more googling finds the more clearly ironic variant "Mexican Jews will replace you" or even "The Reptilian space Jews will replace you".

Comment: Oddly enough the latter is in reference to an actual conspiracy theory again... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reptilian_conspiracy_theory

Answer (score 17):

For what's worth it, the (counter) phrase has been used with the ironic meaning by civil rights advocate
[Lateefah Simon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateefah_Simon), as [quoted by ADL](https://sanfrancisco.adl.org/adl-honors-laura-stein-and-dr-clarence-b-jones/) here:

> In accepting this Award, I want to send a message to surrounding communities in our State, our Nation and the World: That we from the Civil Rights Movement generation remember, especially African Americans. We shall never forget… We are here today to say, what some may be unwilling or uncomfortable **to say publicly to the white racists in Charlottesville, Virginia and to all in our nation responsible for the historic rise in racist hate motivated violence: Oh, yes, the ’Jews’ will replace you!** And so will all of us with them, who are non-Jews, Black, Brown, Asian, Catholics, Protestants, Muslims, Straight or LGBTQ.

(You'll note the scare quotes around "Jews" as ADL transcribed it.)